# Should question proposers be expected to have a coded answer before they propose?

Tags: discussion, policy, rules, challenge-quality

All too often I look at questions proposed here and I think: "The proposer clearly doesn't have a running solution to this question."

Should we make it an expectation that before posting a question, whether code-golf or code-challenge, the poster should have running code that implements the problem. While I don't think they should have to reveal their code at start, perhaps they should reveal what language their implementation is in, and how long it is.

I imagine for code-golf, it isn't important that their answer is golf'd. But, for code-challenge, especially ones with execution time or memory requirements, the poster's solution should conform.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

In a similar vein Joey has been pushing to have a tool to validate the results.

I regard both suggests in a positive light, and would strongly encourage people posting non-trivial questions to consider doing both.

That said, I've been trying to avoid too many hard and fast *"You must jump through this hoop in order to post"* type rules. We have pretty low traffic, and I hesitate to make it worse.

Granted, I think the quality of our questions is less than stellar and that may be contributing to the dearth of traffic.

Please feel free to encourage others to have a working solution before posting. IN particular feel free to suggest that the effort of producing a working model would have allowed the user to identify some of the corner cases left unspecified.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning me :-). And completely agreed. Given that I currently prepare another CG contest at our uni I notice that having one or two reference solutions to tasks helps finding corner cases and parts of the spec that are unclear. And it eases generating test cases by a few orders of magnitude.